# using exapandable/collapsable popups in zk

Tags: popup, zk

I am using zk. I am wondering if ZK supports a way to display collapsable/expandable windows. Say, I have a hyperlink on my webpage. When I click on the hyperlink, instead of navigating to another page I would like to display a collapsable/expandable popup which is attached to the hyperlink like so : http://www.screencast.com/users/sonyv/folders/Default/media/0ce4483a-d23d-4164-82f5-c45a7dfff05b

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 1):

you can use ZK's [popup](http://hudson:3456/zkdemo/menu/pop-ups) component

```
<popup id="mail" width="300px">
    <html><![CDATA[
        Please enter real email address. <br /> The validator
        allow multiple email addresses separated by semi-colons
        (<font color="red">;</font>).<br /> For
        Example:<u>zk@zkoss.org</u>;<u>info@zkoss.org</u>
    ]]></html>
</popup>
```

and customize the style to fit what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<zk>
    <label popup="msg" value="Hyperlink" />
    <popup id="msg">
        <hbox>
            Select a color:
            <combobox />
        </hbox>
    </popup>
</zk>
```

I just tested it in the [Sandbox](http://www.zkoss.org/zksandbox/userguide/#t5). You can put whatever you like inside the *popup*, and you can put it over several type of components (not only *label*).